# Javascript insert value inside an input

Tags: javascript, html

I have to make a function in javascript that compiles this input with a value;

This is what i tried to do

```
document.getElementById("email").value = "testemail@gmail.com";
```

but i get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

html code:

```
    <div>
        <label class="block text-sm text-gray-800 mb-1 dark:text-gray-300" for="email">Email address</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" placeholder="lebron@gmail.com" value="">
        <div class="text-xs text-red-500 mt-1">Please enter your email address.</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Make sure you are calling your script after the actual `<input>` element has been created because the code you provided does work.

Comment: That means the element does not yet exist by the time the script runs.

Comment: Is your script running before the HTML is finished loading? Is the script in the `<head>` of the document?

Comment: If the script is in the `<head>`of the document, consider using the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) event listener. For example: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { document.getElementById('email').value = 'XYZ@gmail.com'; });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your JavaScript in this event listener. This will execute after the page has loaded therefore your email element should be on the page at this point.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById("email").value = "testemail@gmail.com";
})
```